# Running inference from loaded tensorflow model is slow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run live segmentation inference on a webcam using opencv, however I am getting poor fps (around 3 fps). When digging into my code, the problem seems to be that when I am converting the tensor from my graph to a numpy array, it takes over 0.25 seconds. How can I do inference from a tensorflow model without this delay?

I am using tensorflow 2.1.0

Comment: Do you use GPU or CPU?